# How to translate "(surname)老板“ in English

Tags: translation, grammar, sentence-structure

how does one translate '(surname)老板' from Chinese to English?
I understand that the word '老板' means boss/shopkeeper/shop owner/chief, but when a surname is added in front of their position, how exactly can i translate it so it sounds grammatically correct? 
For instance, let's say I want to translate ‘张老板' into English. So ‘张老板' would become 'Boss Zhang/Shopkeeper Zhang' when used in a sentence. But it sounds so odd and awkward somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't translate that. Just say Mr Zhang.

Such obsequiousness is more a Chinese thing.

I call strangers on the street 老板 or 师傅.

在中国， 你真正的老板是你的女朋友！（别忘了！）

Comment: oh? "Mr" can be a substitute for "老板" in this case? :0 Wouldn't the original meaning get lost if it becomes "Mr" though?

Comment: If you translate it to "Mr", you also need to make sure the 老板 is male.

Comment: > 在中国， 你真正的老板是你的女朋友
it couldn't be more true

Comment: Wasn't there a joke somewhere that in some Asian cities, if you get the money, EVERYONE will call you "boss"? Or did I just watch too much Nick Cage movies?

Comment: @Becky: sorry, you are right, that's just my latent chauvinism surfacing! Please don't tell my gf!